# Javascript / jQuery plugin to allow horizontal scroll effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Basically I would like to archive results like that: http://www.pixelapse.com/#

Does someone know any nice plugins for that or good articles explaining how to do such effect. I'm able to google http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/ but maybe you know some alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect is called a carousel. Typically you shift through elements in a list with some sort of animations and controllers.

[This article from Tripwire Magazine](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/01/jquery-carousel.html) should give you a pretty good overview of what's out there. As you can see, a lot of the carousels out there are intended for displaying picture galleries, so it might require a bit of hacking on your part to get the result you want.

Comment: >> out there are intended for displaying picture galleries - exactly! I can see a lot of stuff for carouseling images, but I need carousel HMTL

Comment: Well, basically that's what they all do. You take an `ul` and `display: inline` and then you use JS/jQ to control what portion of the content is displayed. To quote one of the plugins: "jCarousel Lite is a jQuery plugin that carries you on a carousel ride filled with images **and HTML content**." Please take some time to look at the different plugins on the page I linked to.

Comment: I've used jCarousel Lite - it helped! Thanks :)